# How to recover my router

Tags: networking, openwrt

I was trying to create wireless mesh network on Linksys WRT54GL and changed the subnet mask to 255.255.255.255 by mistake.

Now I can't access my router. The reset is not working since I flashed the router with openWRT. I have disabled fail safe so even that is not working. Is there any way to change the subnet back to 255.255.255.0 or to reset.

#### Initial

IP -  192.168.1.1
Subnet -  255.255.255.0

#### After the change

IP 192.168.1.1
Subnet 255.255.255.255

Answer (score -1):

You can hard reset your router by stuck in the reset hole with a paperclip.
Then reconfigre the router in the original way,so backup your information or contact your  internet service provider for help.

Comment: The OP mentioned that resetting does not help as he flashed the router with OpenWRT.